# proof- can NOT be a linear combination

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How can I prove that $X^2-Y,X-Y^2$ CAN NOT be written as a combination of $<X^3-Y^3,X^2Y-X>$ ?

Comment: Can $Y$ or $Y^2$ be written as a "combination" of $Y^3$?

Comment: Obviously not, but I guess I need a stronger proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X^2-Y=p(X,Y)(X^3-Y^3)+q(X,Y)(X^2Y-X)$. Evaluating at $X=0$ gives
$Y=p(0,Y)Y^3$, which is impossible. The same technique works for $X-Y^2$.